# When Does "External" Data Qualify as Material Nonpublic Information?

Tags: stocks, stock-analysis, speculation, insider-trading

For the sake of example, let's say company X is a publicly traded company that manages a chain of department stores.

I go to each storefront and setup security cameras to monitor customer traffic, and then use fancy machine-learning to estimate the quantity and value of all purchases (by the size of the bags, number of customers, etc...). The cameras were set up in accordance with all state and federal regulations.

I find that the resulting stream of data correlates strongly with company X's quarterly earnings.

> Question: Is the above data considered material nonpublic information?

On the one hand, anyone can legally accomplish the above task to obtain the data. On the other hand, the data is not publicly available, nor provided by the company.

Comment: So like this article from 2010: [CNBC - New Big Brother: Market-Moving Satellite Images](https://www.cnbc.com/id/38722872)

Comment: @Morrison Chang: I was thinking the same thing actually, but chose to do my example because you can buy the above data. Was there ever an opinion cast in the parking satellite stuff?

Comment: Check the **Mosaic Theory** from [CFA - Standard II(A) Material Nonpublic Information](https://www.cfainstitute.org/en/ethics/codes/std-of-practice-guidance/stds-of-practice-II-A#mosaic) as your example probably falls under that category. Further examples are on that page.

Comment: Definitions here are not clear-cut and unambiguous. What really matters is whether the SEC thinks a judge will agree that you have used material nonpublic information. Since judges differ, there is no one standard for material nonpublic info. If you ask a lawyer, they will tell you their opinion on how likely it is that your info will be considered such. That's the best that can be done. Generally speaking, we are not lawyers here.